# Kotlin Annotations @param: without primary constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I'm using a XML parser/generator ['simple-xml'](https://github.com/carrotsearch/simplexml-safe/tree/safe) that I use on Android.

Since, I have been updated my model from Java to Kotlin, I had an issue with my library. After debbugging, I find out that an *Annotation* `Element` wasn't working well.

```
'@param:' annotations could be applied only to primary constructor parameters
```

Here is the code in Kotlin, this compile well but shows up error at runtime when using the library.

```kotlin
@Entity(indices = [Index("id")])
@Root
@Order(elements = ["nom", "date"])
class Lot {
    /**
     * Constructeur Lot
     *
     * @param nom          String nom du lot
     * @param date         Date Date du lot
     */
    constructor(nom: String?, date: Date?) {
        this.nom = nom
        this.date = date
    }


    private constructor() // For Room

    @JvmField
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) // For Room
    var id = 0

    @JvmField
    @Element
    var nom: String? = null

    @JvmField
    @Element
    var date: Date? = null
```

This version doesn't compile :

```kotlin
    @JvmField
    @field:Element(name = "date", required = true)
    @param:Element(name = "date", required = true)
    var date: Date? = null
```

I don't know how to turn out the problem, because a need an empty constructor for Room and one with all the parameters but without id.

What are the solutions ?

Comment: `@param` is not an annotation, it's a Javadoc / KDoc thing. It's not affecting the actual compiled code in any way.

Comment: But why, when it's explicited on the `@Element` annotations, that show up this error on compilation time, when it's omitted, it shows up the error on runtime ?

Comment: There is no `@Element` annotation here, nor any `@param:` annotation in this code. Which annotation is causing the error you get? Which file/line of code is causing the error?

Comment: `date` properties ? `param:` has been omitted in this code but I can edit to add the other version that doesn't compile

Comment: I don't know what is the code validator you use, but I suspect you should do something like this: `/** @constructor @param: ... */ class Lot(nom: String?, date: Date?) { constructor() { ... } }`. That means we have primary constructor with params, they are documented and we have a no-arg constructor as well.

Comment: @broot need an empty constructor for Room, In kotlin then I need a secondary constructor with calling ```this(null,null)``` ....

Comment: Well, the error message is very explicit that it allows to document params only in the primary constructor. So for me it sounds like we should have a primary constructor with params and secondary no-arg constructor. Why the opposite?

Comment: @broot For me, the error message is explicit too, but I would know, if there any "Java-way constructor" possibility to avoid to do this. I need to convert all my model to primary constructor.

Comment: @lupaulus I think a better solution is to find a documentation library that's more compatible with Kotlin code.

Comment: @Jorn XML Entity parsing on Android, they aren't many of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `Order` and `Element` annotations and set `Transient` on the `id` field if the order of tags does not matter:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Transient

...

@JvmField
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) // For Room
@field:Transient
var id = 0

...
```

Otherwise, using `@field:Element` without `@param:<...>` should be sufficient:

```
@Entity(indices = [Index("id")])
@Root
@Order(elements = ["nom", "date"])
class Lot {
    /**
     * Constructeur Lot
     *
     * @param nom          String nom du lot
     * @param date         Date Date du lot
     */
    constructor(nom: String?, date: Date?) {
        this.nom = nom
        this.date = date
    }

    private constructor() // For Room

    @JvmField
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) // For Room
    var id = 0

    @JvmField
    @field:Element
    var nom: String? = null

    @JvmField
    @field:Element
    var date: Date? = null
```